# TypeScript and unary operator on nullable value

Tags: javascript, typescript

When writing this code:

```
const num = +localStorage.getItem('whatever');
```

TypeScript complains about the return value of `getItem` that is possibly `null` as shown in this [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbGBeGBqANiYBDTAylCAE64DmApgHRVQCSUliAFAOQDuAFrkwG6USbAJQBuIA). However, the unary operator is perfectly able to handle this case. Indeed, `+null === 0`

```js
console.log(+null === 0);
```

Why is that, and how to fix?

Comment: TypeScript prevents a lot of things that work just fine in JavaScript - that's basically its job.

Comment: I don't agree. It should be able to type any valid JavaScript code.

Comment: `let a=1; a="test";` Javascript will let you do this (this is valid JS). Typescript won't (because you're assigning a string to a number), which is a good thing.

Comment: It would work by correctly typing `a` to `string | number` instead of delegating the inference to TypeScript but I don't see how to cleanly fix my problem. I didn't even type `num` at all

Comment: You could disable [strict null checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig). It's been discussed a lot, see e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21574.

Comment: What about @HaneenMahdin's answer? `Number(localStorage.getItem(...))` should work with Typescript, because `Number(null)` gives `0`

Comment: @JeremyThille Interesting but I don't like to add JS code just to make TS happy.

Comment: @jonrsharpe indeed this seems to be the best answer, thanks

Comment: While it is perfectly valid code, TS is created to prevent such kind of expressions. It is 99% bug in PROD code if somebody does uses `+` with null.  But, this is only my opinion, you might not agree with this. This expression `+null` is forbidden in most strong typed languages

Comment: Or add a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), `as string`. That gets erased in compilation.

Comment: I also thought of `const num = +(localStorage.getItem('whatever') as string);`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it inside a `Number` class and use a exclamation at the end to show that result should be shown, just like show below.

```js
const num = +Number(localStorage.getItem('whatever'))!;
```

Comment: `+` is a shorthand for `Number`, `+Number` is redundant

Comment: The `!` (which doesn't mean _"that result should be shown"_, it's a [non-null assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-)) isn't needed either.

Comment: Indeed. `Number(null)` gives `0`, that's fine

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript restricts type conversion for potentially nullable values for avoid typing issues. If you are surely want to convert value, you can use:

1. Type assertion using `as` keyword:

   ```
   const num = +(localStorage.getItem('whatever') as unknown as string);
   ```

   [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxAIwIbIDYE8ByBXDDALhmgQEswBzGAHxjAIxgF4GmBuAWAChfRIsUADcApgiiiAJgBUQ+ALbJxrGAGoAFIhTps+QjFQQYeMAGswIAO5hDxspSoBKbnx4CIIDKIB0GEFQaIuKSsvJ4SuIuQA)
2. Using [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

   ```
   const num = +localStorage.getItem('whatever')!;
   ```

   [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxAIwIbIDYE8ByBXDDALhmgQEswBzGAHxjAIxgF4GmBuAWAChfRIsUADcApgiiiAJgBUQ+ALbJxrGAGpEKdNnyEAhNz48BEEBlEA6DCCoAKEeMmz5eJeICUHIA)
3. Using [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) primitive wrapper:

   ```
   const num = Number(localStorage.getItem('whatever'));
   ```

   [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgJxAIwIbIDYE8ByBXDDALhmgQEswBzGAHxjAIxgF4GmBuAWAChfRIsUADcApgiiiAJgBUQ+ALbJxrGIuUIAFIhTps+QgEpufHgIggMogHQYQVTSPGTZ8vEvHGgA)

All methods will convert `null` (also any nullish value) to `0`. And you need to handle possible `NaN` in any case.